# iOS/Swift: Handling password reset links

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement the following:

- user receives a link in his email with redirect link to a password reset website.
- when he clicks this link, i don't want him to use safari, i want my app to open and redirect him to a specific controller in my app.

I have tried following along to this: https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/

but it simply wont open my app, safari keeps telling me the address is invalid

How would i achieve this? I'm seriously failing at googling a answer to this question :|

Edit: My guess is because my link starts with https:// and that's not something unique, and safari can't make the difference?

Comment: If you follow the directions in the link you posted, it should work fine to open your app.  However if your emailed link starts with https, it will not open your app but the browser instead.

Comment: Yeah i've caught on to that, so that won't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: You are looking for [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)